# TensorFlow Custom Op Launch CUDA kernels in separate streams

Tags: c++, tensorflow

I've written a custom TensorFlow Op that looks something like a matrix multiplication. It takes in a tensor X with shape (n,p) and another tensor Y with shape (m,p) and outputs a result tensor Z with shape (n,m).

I've successfully written the forward pass in CUDA but during the backward pass I need to compute both dX *and* dY. The computation of dX and dY are completely independent so I'd like to launch one kernel to compute dX and one for dY so they can potentially run in parallel.

The only way I've found in the code to get the stream is `const cudaStream_t& cu_stream = GetCudaStream(ctx);`. So how do I ensure these gradients are done in parallel streams rather than in serial? I imagine this same issue must arise with matrix multiplication but I can't figure out how it's dealt with